# React-Native - can't fetch from connected Android device to localhost endpoint

Tags: json, react-native, localhost, fetch, expo

Im pretty new to React Native and im trying to make an application.
I have a JSON post request that works on Postman and on Expo when i run it on web browser (with http://127.0.0.1:8080). But when i try to run it on an attached Android device my app doesn't actually fetch the data.

As far as i can tell there is some problem with the connection between my phone and my computer. But i can't seem to find it.

Extra info: 
- both devices are connected to my internet
- calls to the firebase API work just fine
- changing the "http://localhost:8080/route" with my computers IPv4 address or 10.0.2.2:8080 doesnt work

Comment: you can connect your device to your computer and run adb reverse to expose localhost to your phone, more info in: https://blog.grio.com/2015/07/android-tip-adb-reverse.html

so in this case it would be `adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try this
 - For android: run the following command in terminal and try again

adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

If it doesn't work try this

- Shake device(android)
- Select dev settings and click "Debug server host & port for device"
- Under debugging type local ip address and port number. (Ex: http://127.0.0.1:8080)